# MySQL - Syntax in update statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, syntax

I need to update a table called "pm" where the "id" column is the value in "$id" variable and the "id2 column value is 1. the columns need to update are "user1read" and "user2read".
when im runnig it it says wrong syntax, can any body help?

```
UPDATE `pm_system`.`pm` SET (user1read='no', user2read='yes') 
WHERE (id='".$id."' and id2='1')
```

thanks.

Comment: remove the `()` eg. `UPDATE pm_system.pm SET user1read='no', user2read='yes' WHERE...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right syntax is here:

```
UPDATE `pm_system`.`pm` SET user1read='no', user2read='yes' WHERE id='".$id."' and id2='1'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like

```
UPDATE `pm_system`.`pm` SET user1read='no', user2read='yes' 
WHERE (id='$id' AND id2='1')
```

Considering that `pm` is your table name

Comment: it is runnig, but not updating the database...

Answer (score 1):

write your query like this..

```
UPDATE `pm_system`.`pm` SET user1read='no', user2read='yes' 
WHERE (id='".$id."' and id2='1')
```

OR

```
UPDATE `pm_system`.`pm` SET user1read='no', user2read='yes' 
WHERE id='".$id."' and id2='1'
```

need not to put, `()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = "UPDATE pm_system.pm SET user1read='no', user2read='yes' WHERE (id='$id' and id2='1')";
```